# How to convert nvarchar to date from one column to another in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I have a column called “Month Year Raw” that has multiple nvarchar type data like this: 202201 and I want to convert that to a column called “Month Year” that will be like “January 2022”.

Comment: Why would you ever store a date in _either_ of these formats? Just store a date (using a `date` data type), and you can _always_ derive either of these formats at query time.

Comment: If you want to read about why using string for dates is so bad @AaronBertrand has a good article on the topic. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type

Comment: Also a bunch more advice around dates here: [Dating Responsibly](https://sqlblog.org/dates).

Comment: Append `'01'` and cast.

Answer (score 3):

This is really bad news. You [shouldn't be storing dates as strings](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type) at all, never mind multiple times (which is just redundant storage for no gain). Even `nvarchar` is bad; why would you ever need to use Unicode characters to represent `yyyyMM`? I know 2020 was bad but you still can't use 4 poop emojis (    `03`).

Store a date as a proper date/time data type, then you get built-in validation, sargable queries, date math, etc. You can always derive these *display* formats where they belong, at *display* time.

Plenty of other advice at [Dating Responsibly](https://sqlblog.org/dates).

Until you can fix this:

```
UPDATE dbo.BadIdeas 
SET [Month Year] = CONCAT
  (
    DATENAME(MONTH, CONVERT(datetime, 
       [Month Year Raw] + '01', 112)),
    ' ', 
    YEAR(CONVERT(datetime, 
       [Month Year Raw] + '01', 112))
  );
```

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=57e758e55d143473cbf24e526e2b7051)

Answer (score 0):

If you're just wondering about the programmatic possibilities - "202201" would take the `LEFT(4)` chars for the year and `RIGHT(2)` chars for the month.  Lets assume you were handed that non-atomic nvarchar string and just needed a one-time ad-hoc query.

You would not add a new column to the table, just select what's needed for output.
There is a built-in SQL Server function called `DATENAME()` that convert numbers into month names.  Since the data is stored in nvarchar you need to convert to a compatible integer in order to use those functions so I'll use `CAST()`.

```
DECLARE @variable nvarchar(100) = '202201'

SELECT DATENAME(MONTH, CAST(RIGHT(@variable, 2) as int)) + ' ' + LEFT(@variable, 4) AS [Answer]
```

Results in output:

January 2022

---

A few things I will point out:

1. nvarchar costs 2 bytes of storage per character plus 2 bytes for the variable overhead.  "202201" costs 14 bytes total. Alternatively, datetime only costs 8 bytes total storage.
2. The datetime datatype is the only datatype designed to work with SQL Server's built-in functions which is why you are being told to store dates in the correct datatype.
3. Combining month and year into the same custom string is a violation of 1NF since the data is not atomic.  When you have non-atomic data you end up having to extract parts of string using `LEFT()` and `RIGHT()`, etc. If you need to use system functions you will have to transform the non-atomic data using `CAST()`.

Example of using a datetime datatype instead:

```
DECLARE @variable2 datetime = '2022-01-01'
SELECT FORMAT (@variable2, 'MMMM yyyy')
```

Also results in:

January 2022

Using the correct datatype results in shorter code, and does not require extracting or transformation of data.